# Markov chains and their distribution ruins

Tags: markov-chains, transition-matrix

you chain.

---

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around finding the stationary distribution when the state space is infinite. Anyone have any tips/advice or a solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<sub>**Note:** the following answer was posted after the OP posted a nearly correct answer in the comment section above.</sub>

---

From $\boldsymbol{\pi}^\top = \boldsymbol{\pi}^\top {\bf P} $, eventually, we obtain

$$ \pi_k = \color{blue}{\left(\frac{p}{1-p}\right)^k \pi_0}$$

for all $k \in \Bbb N$. Since $\boldsymbol{\pi}$ is a [probability mass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function) (PMF), $ \sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty \pi_k = 1 $, which yields

$$\pi_0 = \color{blue}{\dfrac{1-2p}{1-p}}$$

which is positive because $p <  \frac12$.

Comment: @juggernaut Please ask a new question, link it to this one and notify me